# How can I know the parent page ID of the blog page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a theme. I know how to retrieve the parent page of a child page. That is very straight forward.

```
global $post;
$parent_page = $post->post_parent
// do with the post parent id whatever you need
```

But my main problem is ....
I set a page **'right sidebar'** as the blog page in where all the posts are being displayed. As well as I set the right  sidebar page as child page of the **'Blog'** page. Then I search on the right sidebar page using `var_dump ( $post )` I could't find any property value of `[post_parent]=> int(0)`. But the post parent has 25 ID.

How can I know the parent page id of a page which has been set as the blog page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `page_for_posts` option:

```
$posts_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
```

> The ID of the page that displays posts. Useful when *show_on_front*'s value is page.
>
> -- [WordPress Codec](https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference)

Comment: Hello I think you don't get my question. Actually I want the ID of the parent page of the child page which has been set as 'Posts page' from setting->reading->a static page-> posts page == that child page.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by doing some experiments. Finally the answer is

```
global $wp_query;
$parent_post_id = $wp_query->queried_object->post_parent;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this function add in your theme functions.php file. This function will return the page id from the parent page.

```
function get_top_parent_page_id() { 
    global $post; 

    if ($post->ancestors) { 
        return end($post->ancestors); 
    } else { 
        return $post->ID; 
    } 
}
```